# spring 4.1.7 and clustered ehcache configuration possible?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

my ehcache config starts like this:

```
<ehcache   maxBytesLocalHeap="200M" updateCheck="false">
```

after experiencing error like "maxEntriesLocalHeap is not compatible with maxBytesLocalHeap set on cache manager" I looked into the source of spring-context-support:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public EhCacheFactoryBean() {
        setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(10000);
        setMaxElementsOnDisk(10000000);
        setTimeToLiveSeconds(120);
        setTimeToIdleSeconds(120);
    }
```

The call to setMaxElementsOnDisk is commented like this:

```
void net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration.setMaxElementsOnDisk(int maxElementsOnDisk)



Deprecated. use setMaxEntriesLocalDisk(long) for unclustered caches and setMaxEntriesInCache(long) for clustered caches.

Sets the maximum number elements on Disk. 0 means unlimited. 

This property can be modified dynamically while the cache is operating.

Parameters:
maxElementsOnDisk the maximum number of Elements to allow on the disk. 0 means unlimited.
```

Does this mean that using spring 4.1.7 together with its dependency ehcache 2.9.1 a clustered cache is impossible using springs EhCacheFactoryBean?

Best regards,
Carsten

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I fail to see the link between the code/documentation snippets and your conclusion. Can you elaborate?

One thing is that it seems the default cache creation from Spring conflicts with what you want to do at the `CacheManager` level. But if you do not use default caches, you should have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

CacheManager and cache must use the same configuration parameters  maxBytesLocalHeap  or maxEntriesLocalHeap, and MaxElements* is Deprecated